# Uncaught Reference Error: openCity() is not defined

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make a from using which, I can store image into psql. The DB has one table with two fields, ID and IMG bytea type. The page contains 2 tabs. It has a function 'openCity' to load tabs on click.

The tabs/form were working fine. I started implementing image store functionality, add some code for that. But now when I click any tab to test if image store code works, it raises exception 'openCity is not defined'.

How to remove this error/exception.

**Here is my code:**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <body>
        <?php
        require("connection.php");
        ?>
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 align="center">DB Form </h1>
          <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Insert Record')">Insert Record</button>
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Search Database')">Search Database</button>

        </div>
    <div id="Insert Record" class="tabcontent">

       <form action="" method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <h2> Field </h2>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
          <label for="validationCustom01">Field ID</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="field_id" id="field_id" placeholder="insert field id" value="" required>
          <div class="valid-feedback">
            0
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
          <label for="validationCustom02">IMG</label>
          <input type="file" class="form-control" name="img" id="img" placeholder="insert" value="" required>
          <div class="valid-feedback">
            Looks good!
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>      

      <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit1" type="submit">Insert Records</button>
    </form>


        <?php

              if(isset($_POST["submit1"])){


                  $file_name = $_POST["img"];

                  $img = fopen($file_name, 'r') or die("cannot read image\n");
                  $data = fread($img, filesize($file_name));

                  $es_data = pg_escape_bytea($data);
                  fclose($img);

                try {

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO fields (field_id, img)
                    VALUES ('".$_POST["field_id"]."','".$es_data."')";
                    if ($conn->query($sql)) {
                         echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('New Record Inserted Successfully');</script>";
                              }
                              else{
                                echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Data not successfully Inserted.');</script>";
                          }
                                $dbh = null;
                        }
                            catch(PDOException $e)
                        {
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                            }
                        }   

                        //$conn = null;

                        ?>

</div>

<div id="Search Database" class="tabcontent">     
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: The HTML view of your page seems OK. But, being the function defined after the main body contents, thare are chances that some error occurred when executing the PHP script, which delivered an incomplete page to the browser. See the server's error log and the source HTML in the browser.

Comment: @LittleSanti: Before putting the file upload code after if(isset) $file_name = $_POST["img"];
                  $img = fopen($file_name, 'r') or die("cannot read image\n");
                  $data = fread($img, filesize($file_name));
                  $es_data = pg_escape_bytea($data);
                  fclose($img);
It was/is working fine. But it shows this error when I put it. I even can't check that's working OR is it correct way to put it there. Can you please see this file upload code.

Comment: I can't tell by the page you posted. Your previous comment confirms my impression that the cause is located at the PHP code. You must debug the PHP script and see what is the error that happened at the server side. Most probably it is related to the connection or the data you are trying to insert.

Comment: did you check in the console if there is any other javascript error before `openCity()` declaration?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs in the browser and the browser cannot see your PHP code. You can see the actual code that runs in the browser with the *View Source* feature, which is typically mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. There're you can see there's no trace of the `openCity()` definition when the error happens.

Your code totally breaks when you submit the form because you [abort](https://php.net/die) abruptly if the image cannot be found:

```
die("cannot read image\n")
```

... and there's no chance that an image can ever be found because you read it from a form field:

```
$file_name = $_POST["img"];
```

... that does not exist because the form control is of `file` type:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="img" id="img" placeholder="insert" value="" required>
```

... and [file uploads don't work that way](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

There're some additional problems, mainly blatant security wholes:

- SQL injection

  ```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO fields (field_id, img) VALUES ('".$_POST["field_id"]."','".$es_data."')";
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```
- Potential free access to arbitrary files (due to upload mishandle):

  ```
  $file_name = $_POST["img"];
  $img = fopen($file_name, 'r')
  ```
- [Misuse of exception handling](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#catch):

  ```
  catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
  }
  ```

But I think the main problem is a lack of flow design. The code is not organised in such a way that errors can be handled properly.